# How can I visualize correctly my trades in backtesting.py?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithmic-trading, technical-indicator, rsi

Im trying to backtest a RSI and Bollinger Bands based strategy to a OHCLV BTC dataset. When I plot the strategy, trades do not look like open and close at the given conditions and I really do not understand what's wrong with my code.
In particular I want to open a long position and close the short position when the RSI in below 25 and the closing price is below the lowest Bollinger band. Whereas, I want to open a short and close the long position when the price in above the highest Bollinger band and the RSI is above 85.

```
import pandas as pd
import talib as ta
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy
from backtesting.lib import crossover

df = pd.read_csv('XBTEUR_60.csv')
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], unit="s")
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'open': 'Open', 'high': 'High', 'low': 'Low', 'close': 'Close', 'volume': 'Volume'})
df = df.drop('trades', axis=1)

#functions variables
alfaL=0.9
alfaS=1.05
timeperiod_BB=20
timeperiod_RSI=14
nbdevup=1
nbdevdn=1

class BollingerBands(Strategy):
    
    #functions variables
    RSI_UB=85
    RSI_LB=25

    def init(self):
        self.BBands = self.I(ta.BBANDS, self.data.Close, timeperiod_BB, nbdevup, nbdevdn)
        self.rsi = self.I(ta.RSI, self.data.Close, timeperiod_RSI)

    def next(self):
        
        if (self.data.Close[-1]>self.BBands[2][-1] and self.rsi[-1]> self.RSI_UB):
            if self.position.is_long or not self.position:
                self.position.close()
                self.sell(size= 0.1, sl=alfaS*self.data.Close[-1])
        
        elif (self.data.Close[-1]<self.BBands[0][-1] and self.RSI_LB> self.rsi[-1]):
            if self.position.is_short or not self.position:
                self.position.close()
                self.buy(sl=alfaL*self.data.Close[-1])


bt = Backtest(df, BollingerBands, cash=10_000, commission=0.00023)
stats = bt.run()

print(stats)

bt.plot()
```

[this is the result when plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pbhP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and calc you signal OUTSIDE the strategy class as a column in your DF that you are going to use. Then you can see if you are getting proper signals. Then run the backtest on the signal for example:

```
df['signal'] = 0
if (self.data.Close[-1]>self.BBands[2][-1] and self.rsi[-1]> self.RSI_UB):
   df['signal'] = 1 #long
elif (self.data.Close[-1]<self.BBands[0][-1] and self.RSI_LB> self.rsi[-1]):
  df['signal'] = 2 #short
```

then you can pass it in
class BreadthStrat(Strategy):
# atr_f = 0.2
atr_f = 1

```
def init(self):
    super().init()
    self.signal1 = self.I(SIGNAL)

def next(self):
    super().next()
    for trade in self.trades: 
        if trade.is_long: 
            trade.sl = max(trade.sl or -np.inf, self.data.Close[-1] - self.data.Close[-1] * PER_F)


    if self.signal1==2 and len(self.trades)==0: # trades number change!
        sl1 = self.data.Close[-1] - self.data.Close[-1] * PER_F
        self.buy(sl=sl1)
```